# Python - outlook not seeing the emails from today

Tags: python, email, outlook, attachment, email-attachments

I am trying to download the files/reports that i receive every day from Transportation System.

Already wrote some code (i am just starting with Python so it could not look very professional) but when i am trying to get to the newest emails- program is not able to recognize them.

I checked the len(email) and it showed 2552 emails. When i went to the newest from this "catalog" (2552) it was last email from yesterday (2019-02-15), although today(2019-02-16) i already have an email with an attachment.

Should i modify the syntax as for "email" variable that i am using here ( i guess that this could be an issue that it somehow does not encompass all emails there)?

Will be really grateful for help!

Code is as below:

```
import win32com.client

folder = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6)

subfolder=folder.Folders(3)

email = subfolder.Items

message = email.Item(2252)

attachment = message.Attachments.Item(1)

attachment.SaveAsFile(r'C:\Users\310295192\Desktop\report.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never sort the Items collection, it won't be in any particular order. Try to sort it by the `ReceivedTime` property:

```
email.Sort "ReceivedTime", false
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Dmitry! Checked the code you wrote, adjusted it a little bit (i put "ReceivedTime" in parentheses since without them i was getting a syntax error) and it worked perfectly fine! I hope that the biggest obstacle is behind me. Already have an idea how to go further with processing these daily reports.

Comment: Sorry about the parentheses  - I thought you were using VBS. If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!